# como establecer un tiempo maximo de respuesta en ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

tengo una llamada mediante ajax que me regresa una respuesta, lo que quiero hacer es, por ejemplo hay veces que la respuesta demora mucho y en estos casos quisiera poner un mensaje que diga algo como que su petición demoro mas de lo permitido, por ejemplo que aparezca este mensaje despues de 20 segundos

le paso mi codigo de la peticion gracias:

```
function generarnombre(){


      $("#cargando").css("display", "inline");

     $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url : "reniec.php",
       data : $("#fromulariof1").serialize(),
       success : function(data){
                 $("#resultado_reniec").html(data);
                     $("#cargando").css("display", "none");

       }  

      })

      return false;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Facil, puedes utilizar el método `timeout` para poner un tiempo máximo de respuesta. Algo tal que así:

```
function generarnombre(){


  $("#cargando").css("display", "inline");

 $.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : "reniec.php",
   data : $("#fromulariof1").serialize(),
   success : function(data){
             $("#resultado_reniec").html(data);
                 $("#cargando").css("display", "none");

   },
   timeout: 20000, // sets timeout to 20 seconds  
   error: function(request, status, err) {
        if (status == "timeout") {
            alert("Su petición demoro mas de lo permitido");
        } else {
            // another error occured  
            alert("error: " + request + status + err);
        }
    }
  })

  return false;

}
```

Comment: y donde pongo el mensaje?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta. En el error, añades una condición de que si el status es timeout te devuelva el alert con el error.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes establecer el valor de la propiedad `timeout` (en milisegundos) en la petición ajax.

Si llega al tiempo establecido se ejecutará la función de error y en la propiedad `statusText` tendrá un valor `timeout`:

```js
function generarnombre(){


      $("#cargando").css("display", "inline");

     $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url : "reniec.php",
       data : $("#fromulariof1").serialize(),
       success : function(data){
                 $("#resultado_reniec").html(data);
                     $("#cargando").css("display", "none");

       },
       error: function(e){
        if (e.statusText==='timeout'){
          console.log('Tiempo de espera agotado');
        }
        else{
          console.log(e.statusText);
        }
       },
       timeout: 20000
      });

      return false;

}

$(function(){
  generarnombre();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cargando"></div>
```